# How to iterate over rows and multiple columns in panda?

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have a dataframe (df1) and I want to replace the values for the columns V2 and V3 if they have the same value than V1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_start= pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 2 , 3 ,4, 5], "V1":[10,5,15,20,20], "V2":[10,5,20,17,15], "V3":[10, 25, 15, 10, 20]})

df_end = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 2 , 3 ,4, 5], "V1":[10,5,15,20,20], "V2":[np.nan,np.nan,20,17,15], "V3":[np.nan, 25, np.nan, 10, np.nan]})
```

I know iterrows is not recommended but I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: `df_end['V2'] = df_end['V2'].fillna(df_end['V1']); df_end['V3'] = df_end['V3'].fillna(df_end['V1'])`?

Comment: @Yo_Chris I think that's the opposite of what OP is asking for. They're not looking to fill the null values from V1. They're looking to replace the values in the columns of df_start if the value for that row matches the value in V1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mask`:

For a seperate dataframe use `assign`:

```
df_end = df_start.assign(**df_start[['V2','V3']]
                        .mask(df_start[['V2','V3']].eq(df_start['V1'],axis=0)))
```

For modifying the input dataframe just assign inplace:

```
df_start[['V2','V3']] = (df_start[['V2','V3']]
                      .mask(df_start[['V2','V3']].eq(df_start['V1'],axis=0)))
```

---

```
   ID  V1    V2    V3
0   1  10   NaN   NaN
1   2   5   NaN  25.0
2   3  15  20.0   NaN
3   4  20  17.0  10.0
4   5  20  15.0   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Just to be sure I understand you first evaluate for each row of df_start the cases where V2/V3 == V1 and then mask when it's True? I don't understand the difference what the '**' represents

Comment: @yyzzz exactly , also `**` is used as a kwarg to unpack the dataframe into 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

You'll still use a regular loop to go through the columns, but the apply function is your best friend for this kind of row-wise operation. If you're going to use info from more than one column (here you're comparing some column and "V1"), you use apply on the DataFrame and specify the axis. If you were only looking at info from one column (like making a column that doubles values from V1 if they're even, you can use apply with just a Series.

For both versions of the function, the argument you're going to pass is a lambda expression. If you apply it do a DataFrame like you are here, the `x` represents the values in a row that can be indexed by a column. Finally, you assign the result back to a new or existing column in your DataFrame.

Assuming that df_start and df_end represent your planned input and output:

```
cols = ["V2","V3"]
for col in cols:
    df_start[col] = df.apply(lambda x[col] if x[col] != x["V1"] else np.nan, axis=1]
```

Comment: Try avoiding apply when possible,  it takes a performance hit as compared to vectorized methods